# how to configure 24/7 running Spark streaming with yarn

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, oozie

I have spark-streaming application and currently we run it with oozie.
I have a problem that if the driver crashed, oozie doesn't manage this situation and my application will not run until manually event.

I read about the rerun option in oozie and am wondering how to manage spark streaming applications that do not need scheduling - always executed and able to auto rerun on failure (memory \ node crashed etc).

Comment: BTW, i saw this flag, spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts - is it mean also if driver killed after 2 hours it will relaunch it ?

Comment: Oozie is designed to run batch jobs, not permanent services -- you're using the wrong tool! Run the driver as a Linux service on an Edge Node instead..